# How to set mutliple text boxes size using MVC/ CSS3,4/ jQuery?

Tags: jquery, .net, css, model-view-controller

Is there a way where we can set the size of multiple textboxes at one go, maybe during page initialization?

For example: I have 20 text boxes on my web page and I want to restrict user not to enter more than 50 characters in 5 of those, 100 chars in another 5 textboxes etc. I don't want to set each textbox size during run time as these things may change dynamically. I will read the length specifications from a config file.

Is there any solution using jQuery, MVC4/5, Javascript?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly then this would be more ideally done with with the server-side language.  Import variables from config file into controller, pass them to your view and run the appropriate loops for each set of textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I believe the easiest way is set through jquery.

Razor:

@Html.Text("txt", new {@class='txt50'})

@Html.Text("txt2", new {@class='txt100'})

Use class txt50 and txt100 in your textbox.

Jquery part:

```
$(function(){
   $(".txt50").each(function(){
      var txt = $(this);

      txt.attr('maxlength','50');
   });

   $(".txt100").each(function(){
      var txt = $(this);

      txt.attr('maxlength','100');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This jquery function will do all textboxes on the page

```
 $("input:text").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $(document.getElementById(id)).attr('maxlength', 50);
        });
```